# How to remove spacing between a Text and a labeless Stepper in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
VStack {
    HStack {
        Text("Hello World")                 
    }
    Stepper("", value: $test, in: 0...2)   
}
```

There is substantial space between the Text and the Stepper. How do I get rid of this spacing?

Comment: HStack(spacing: 0) and VStack(spacing: 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set VStack `spacing`:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    HStack {
        Text("Hello World")                 
    }
    Stepper("", value: $test, in: 0...2)   
}
```